# MariaDB: Host '127.0.0.1' not privileged

Tags: mariadb

My Ghost instance want to conntect to my MariaDB, but the error is:

```
Message: 'ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED: Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server'
```

Here my my.cnf:

```
[server]
skip-name-resolve
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 64M
tmp_table_size= 64M
max_heap_table_size= 64M
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time = 1
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

[client-server]
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
binlog_format = MIXED
innodb_large_prefix=on
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that your problem is that you've set `skip-name-resolve`.

By default, the MySQL/MariaDB user database contains only entries that allow access from `localhost`. But if you skip name resolution, then MySQL doesn't translate your connection from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`, and thus can't match your connection to any host that's allowed to connect.

Remove `skip-name-resolve` and try again.

If you really want to keep this option, you'll need to create MySQL users who can connect from `::1` (and `127.0.0.1` if you still use IPv4) while `skip-name-resolve` is disabled, and then re-enable it.